# User named "Guest" in user list of LightDM greeter

Tags: xubuntu, 20.04

Actually I have two of them. They are not visible in the "Users Settings" tool and there is nothing about them in `/home`. I guess they exist due to unclean exits from guest-sessions I had to do because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-session/+bug/1855350). How do you get rid of the "Guest"s?

Comment: BTW it would help, if you could test, if the bug applies to other DEs besides Xfce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -o '^guest-[^:]*' /etc/passwd
```

gave me the user ids of the accounts.

Then I could remove the users by

```
sudo deluser userid
```